# SVG polygon animation bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a bug on `http://goalbot.co/`
There is a red background svg polygon animation. which should take up only 50% of height at bottom side. [Normal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3zdl.png)

But if you navigate or refresh page and instantly switch to other browser tab during the svg animation, and then come back, you'd notice SVG took much more space until all the screen. [Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFAka.png)

Whats going on there?

Comment: Email the web-design team.

Comment: I'd happy with this, but only reason what the hell polygon takes antire screen if tab has changed